# The existence of a smooth family for every singular scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that we are given a (irreducible) singular scheme $X$ of finite type over a (perfect) field $k$.

Is it possible to find a flat family of schemes $$f \colon \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{A}^1$$ such that $X \simeq f^{-1}(0)$ and where the generic fibre $X_t$ is smooth over $k$?

If so, is the family canonical? If not, are there any restrictions we can put on $X$ to make it work?

In general, are there ways of ''smoothening'' $X$ similarly to how Nagata's compactification theorem allows one to ''compactify'' $X$?

Comment: Take a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56019/degenerations-of-smooth-projective-varieties, specifically the answer of Sándor Kovács.